# Поймать свайп вправо

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть объект `<div class="music--container">`. Как на JS поймать тот момент, когда 50% левой области объекта пытаются потянуть вправо и выполнить к примеру `console.info('Вы потянули объект вправо')`??

P.s: желательно без плагинов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте:

```js
let x;
addEventListener('touchstart', e => x = e.changedTouches[0].clientX);
addEventListener('touchend', e => e.changedTouches[0].clientX - x < -50 && swipeLeft());

function swipeLeft() {
    console.log('swipe left')
}
```

Comment: А на определенный объект повесить событие нельзя?

Comment: можно внутри этого проверять от какого элемента пришел эвент (e.target указывает на элемент, на котором сработало событие)

Comment: Например, если сделать свайп по изображению, то `e.target` вернет его. В `music--container` находятся `img,span,a`. Когда `e.target` вернет элемент, как проверить находится ли это элемент в `music--container`?

Comment: @OlimpES .parentNode указывает на родителя